Do I publish the coin via a pull-request?
this is my first time developing a coin using Solana CLI. I have created a keypair, a minting wallet, a coin and minted the first batch. But how do I publish it? ChatGPT suggests to create a token_metadata.json with the following payload:
{
"chainId": 101,
"address": "<token address>",
"symbol": "<symbol>",
"name": "<name>",
"decimals": 9,
"logoURI": "https://path.to/your/logo.png",
"tags": [
  "utility-token"
]
}

Then fork this repo: https://github.com/solana-labs/token-list
And submit a pull request with this metadata.json.
Is this the correct/best practice approach or are there better ways? Using solana cli(devnet) with a Ubuntu terminal on Windows. If there is a step-by-step guide somewhere, I would appreciate a link.

Be sure to read the links that you're providing. The token-list has been deprecated for two years.

I would advise you to first look at the documentation and understand how tokens work on Solana.
The docs cover everything https://solana.com/docs/core/tokens takes you through what tokens are and how to create them.
Onchain examples can also be found here https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/tree/main/tokens/create-token/anchor/programs/create-token
